# How to generalize this combined PreRead + PrePrint code?

Tags: output-formatting

***NOTE: The finished code for this project can be found here, under "UPDATE":
[How do I alter this \$PreRead + \$PrePrint statement so it can be selectively deactivated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138800/how-do-i-alter-this-preread-preprint-statement-so-it-can-be-selectively-de)***

I'm trying to generalize some very nice code posted by Mr. Wizard ([Notebook formatting - easier descriptions for equations and results?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11961/notebook-formatting-easier-descriptions-for-equations-and-results/11987#11987)); this code allows one to follow a MMA command with text, on a single line, with minimal added syntax (while not having any effect on the ability of the output of the MMA command to be evaluated).  Here's Mr. Wizard's original code, and a sample input and 
output:

```
$note = Null;

$PreRead =
Replace[#,
RowBox[{body__, ";", note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :>
 ($note = Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red]; RowBox[{body}])
] &;

$PrePrint = 
If[$note =!= Null,
 # &[Row[{Pane@#, Spacer[50], $note}], $note = Null],
 #
] &;
```

`Integrate[x^2, x]; "Text after."`

> $\frac{x^3}{3} \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\> \color{red}{\textit {Text after.}}$

I'd like to generalize Mr. Wizard's code to allow one to insert text either before, or after, or both, to allow, in addition to the above:

`"Text before."; Integrate[x^2, x]`

> $\color{red}{\textit {Text before.}} \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\> \frac{x^3}{3}$

and

`"Text before."; Integrate[x^2, x]; "Text after."`

> $\color{red}{\textit {Text before.}} \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\> \frac{x^3}{3} \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\> \color{red}{\textit {Text after.}}$

In attempting to modify the code, I've been able to get it to work for each of the above conditions individually, but not to handle all three together.  I suspect the main problem is my \$PreRead statement, which may need a set of Which[ ] conditions to allow it to recognize all three patterns; but I haven't been able to figure out how to write such a pattern-matcher within a \$PreRead.  Here's an example of what I have thus far, which works only if the input has text both before and after the MMA command, or no text at all:

```
$note1 = Null;
$note2 = Null;

$PreRead = 
Replace[#, 
RowBox[{note1_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &), ";", body__, 
   ";"  , note2_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :> ($note1 =
    Style[ToExpression@note1, Italic, Red]; $note2 = 
   Style[ToExpression@note2, Italic, Red]; 
  RowBox[{body}])] &;

$PrePrint = Which[
($note1 =!= Null && $note2 =!= Null), # &[
 Row[{$note1, Spacer[50], Pane@#, Spacer[50], $note2}], $note1 = 
  Null, $note2 = Null],
($note1 =!= Null && $note2 === Null), # &[
 Row[{$note1, Spacer[50], Pane@#}], $note1 = Null],
($note1 === Null && $note2 =!= Null), # &[
 Row[{Pane@#, Spacer[50], $note2}], $note2 = Null],
True, #
] &;
```

The above only works for this:

`"Text before."; Integrate[x^2, x]; "Text after."`

> $\color{red}{\textit {Text before.}} \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\> \frac{x^3}{3} \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\> \color{red}{\textit {Text after.}}$

...and this:

`Integrate[x^2, x]`

> $\frac{x^3}{3}$

---

**UPDATE: For the convenience of the reader, here is the corrected code, which incorporates the answer provided by MB1965.  This generalizes Mr.Wizard's code, allowing inline text to be easily inserted before MMA code, after MMA code, both before and after, or by itself (the latter maintains consistent text output formatting when you want to enter just text into a cell). Syntax for text+math is as shown above. For text by itself, just use `"Text";`**

```
$note1 = Null;
$note2 = Null;
$note3 = Null;
$PreRead = 
Replace[#, {RowBox[{note1_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &), ";", 
    body__, ";", 
    note2_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :> ($note1 = 
    Style[ToExpression@note1, Italic, Red]; $note2 = 
    Style[ToExpression@note2, Italic, Red];
   RowBox[{body}]),
 RowBox[{body__, ";", 
    note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :> ($note2 = 
    Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red];
   $note1 = Null;
   RowBox[{body}]),
 RowBox[{note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &), ";", 
    body__}] :> ($note1 = Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red];
   $note2 = Null;
   RowBox[{body}]),
 RowBox[{note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &), 
    ";"}] :> ($note3 = Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red];
   $note2 = Null; $note1 = Null;
   RowBox[{note}]),
 e_ :> ($note1 = Null; $note2 = Null; e)}] &;
$PrePrint = Which[($note1 == Null && $note2 == Null && $note3 =!= 
   Null), # &[$note3, $note3 = Null],
($note1 =!= Null && $note2 =!= Null && $note3 == Null), # &[
 Row[{$note1, Spacer[50], Pane@#, Spacer[50], $note2}], $note1 = 
  Null, $note2 = Null],
($note1 =!= Null && $note2 =!= Null && $note3 == Null), # &[
 Row[{$note1, Spacer[50], Pane@#, Spacer[50], $note2}], $note1 = 
  Null, $note2 = Null],
($note1 =!= Null && $note2 === Null && $note3 == Null), # &[
 Row[{$note1, Spacer[50], Pane@#}], $note1 = Null],
($note1 === Null && $note2 =!= Null && $note3 == Null), # &[
 Row[{Pane@#, Spacer[50], $note2}], $note2 = Null], True, #] &;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Replace` can take a list of replacements to try as its second argument. Simply catenate all your patterns in a list and use `Replace` with that. i.e.,

```
$PreRead = Replace[#, {
     RowBox[{note1_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &), ";", body__, 
        ";", note2_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :> ($note1 = 
        Style[ToExpression@note1, Italic, Red]; $note2 = 
        Style[ToExpression@note2, Italic, Red];
       RowBox[{body}]),
     RowBox[{body__, ";", 
        note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &)}] :> ($note2 = 
        Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red];
       $note1 = Null;
       RowBox[{body}]), 
     RowBox[{note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &), ";", 
        body__}] :> ($note1 = Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red];
       $note2 = Null;
       RowBox[{body}]), e_ :> ($note1 = Null; $note2 = Null; e)}] &;
```

Note that I also put in a "doesn't match" pattern at the end to make sure the notes are cleared if not used.

Comment: Changing `note_String` to `note_String2` will actually invalidate it. That checks for a `String2` expression rather than just a `String`. Also yeah, I'll change the order in which `Replace` checks.

Comment: Updated. Now it checks for both first, then before, then after. An oversight on my part. Also if the answer doesn't actually do what you need it to, consider waiting to accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I've confirmed this works.  [BTW, in my earlier comment, I meant to write `note2_String` not `note_String2`.]

Comment: Can you explain how `e_ :> $note1 = Null; $note2 = Null; e` works?  I gather it means that "if nothing matches, don't replace anything, and clear the notes".  But how does `e_` correspond to "nothing matches", and what is the purpose of writing the `e` at the end?

Comment: The underscore is a shorthand for `Blank[]` which matches anything. `e` is the symbol that captures the matched value. I had to put it at the end because we need to return the thing `$PreRead` is reading or else it won't do anything. Run this to learn more: ``Documentation`HelpLookup@"tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules"``

Comment: What is that? It's a rather simplistic pattern so I wouldn't expect it to catch all cases of interesting.

Comment: I just noticed the code doesn't work for a corner case I didn't mention in my question:  for cases where the math isn't printed (such as delayed assignments), the text won't be printed, e.g `"g[x_]:=Sin[x]; "Text after."`  Is this an easy fix, or should I post a separate question?  The rationale for wanting this is that ultimately I want to combine this code with code that does print delayed assignments (see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134406/would-like-input-and-output-printed-on-same-line-w-o-needing-extra-syntax), to enable me to combine input, output, & text on one line.

Comment: I can wrangle that up in a bit. It shouldn't be hard to do. You can probably even do it yourself, I imagine, given what we have here. Try looking at FullForm@Unevaluated[g[x_]:=Sin[x];]  to figure out what that pattern looks like.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll play with it.  BTW, I was just able to extend it to cases where there's no math at all (text only), to give consistent text output formatting, by adding this to the Replacement statement (along with a corresponding condition to the Which statement, and `$note3=Null;` at the beginning):  `RowBox[{note_String?(StringMatchQ[#, "\"*\""] &), ";"}] :> ($note3 = 
   Style[ToExpression@note, Italic, Red];
  $note2 = Null; $note1 = Null;
  RowBox[{note}])`

Comment: I'm confused by the second argument of the StringMatchQ in the current code, because that looks like a regular expression rather than a string expression, but in the documentation it says that using a regex within StringMatchQ requires this syntax, which is not being used here:  `StringMatchQ["string",RegularExpression["regex"]]`.  Also, the site's AI is asking me to move this discussion to chat (because of its length); I'll leave it up to your discretion, as the more experienced user, whether we should do this.

Comment: So StringMatchQ has an operator form so using it as a function like that is actually unnecessary. But even past that there are some regex like features of the String functions. Look at the StringReplace docs for more info, but * matches 0+ characters, hence its usage here.

Comment: So I should interpret `"\"*\""` as a string expression, rather than a regex?

Comment: At some lower level it may get used as a regex but at this level, yes, it is a string with a special meaning in string matching functions. To match an explicit "*" you have to escape it. There are various tutorials linked in the docs that can explain all this much better than I, but basically the RegularExpression head simply forces interpretation as a regex but for a few commonly used cases WRI has allowed regex-like matching in plain strings.

Comment: I'm at a loss.  I wonder if the problem is that, while this code uses `body__` to pattern-match the math (where `__` captures "any sequence of one or more Wolfram Language expressions" [ref.: Help docs.]),   evaluating `ToBoxes[g[x_] := Sin[x]]` returns "Null", indicating there's nothing there to match (?).  Note, however, that after evaluating the code (linked in comment #7) with which I'll be merging this code, I find `ToBoxes[g[x_] := Sin[x]]` instead returns "ToBoxes[g(x_):=sin(x)]=Null" — so maybe it would be easiest to address this post-merge rather than pre-merge (?).

Comment: You need to check ToBoxes@Unevaluated[g[x_]:=Sin[x];]. I believe $PreRead processes before submission to the kernel. I think the issue is the Null return to $PrePrint. So it doesn't even bother to print anything. Try g[x_]:=Sin[x]; "No Result"; "Text"

Comment: Interesting.  These all work:  `g[x_] := Sin[x]; ""; "Text"`  `"Text before"; g[x_] := Sin[x]; ""; "Text after"`  `"Text"; g[x_] := Sin[x]; ""; ""`

Comment: Yeah. Just whenever it encounters a Null return it doesn't bother to even check $PrePrint and simply returns nothing.